# In Excel, how do I sum a range of data while ignoring duplicate criteria?

Tags: excel-formula, duplicates, countif, sumifs, openoffice-calc

I am making a (simplified) weekly schedule as shown below. Employees are assigned different rooms with varying quantities of cages that need to be changed. Some rooms are large and require multiple days to complete, which is why they are listed multiple times on the schedule.

[image: Weekly Schedule]

Naturally, the weekly total cages would be calculated disregarding the duplicate rooms on the schedule; I did this manually in column G. How do I achieve this using formulas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] - This does not seem like a programming question so it is not suitable for here .  Try superuser.com?

Answer (score 0):

It is a little tricky having the rooms be in an array rather than a column or row for each individual, but you can work around that if you have the newest version of Excel by first joining the rooms into a string, then breaking the string into substrings with something like:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(
TEXTJOIN(",",1,B2:E3),
 ",", "</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s")
```

From there it is easy. Get the unique values with `UNIQUE`, then extract the cages with something like `INDEX` and `SUM` the result.

So in total something like:

```
=SUM(INDEX($B$8:$C$14, MATCH(
UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(
TEXTJOIN(",",1,B2:E3),
 ",", "</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s")), $B$8:$B$14,0), 2))
```

For example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `F2`, formula copied down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(B$8:B$14,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",,B2:E3)&"</b></a>","//b[preceding::*=.=0]"),C$8:C$14))
```

[image]